# Prove that $x_n = n^7 / 7^n$ tends to 0 by comparison

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence
\begin{align}
x_n = \frac{n^7}{7^n}
\end{align}
I proved by the definition that $(x_n)_n$ tends to 0. However, I want to make another solution by comparing this sequence with a bigger one that tends to zero. How could I do that?. I guessed that
\begin{align}
\forall n \geq 10: n^8 \leq 7^n.
\end{align}
But, unfortunately, I could not prove this inequality.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint $\frac{n^7}{7^n} < \frac{1}{n}$ simplifies to

$n^8 < 7^n \iff 8\log n < n \log 7 \iff \frac{\log n}{n} < \frac{\log 7}{8}$.

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n}{n}$ is known to be $(0)$.

Therefore, for all but a finite number of terms in the sequence,

$\frac{n^7}{7^n} < \frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

Can you show: $$\frac{n^7}{7^n}<\frac{1}{2^n}$$

It is equivalent to: $$n^7<3.5^n$$

Comment: This equation is incorrect.

Comment: @HusseinEid Well, it's not true for small $n$. It is certainly true for all $n$ larger than a certain benchmark.